# How to use the strategy pattern with STL containers?

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, containers, covariance

Assume that I have a strategy interface named `BinaryClassifier` that can take a `Sample` and return a `double` representing the probability of a `Sample` object of belonging to the positive class:

```
struct BinaryClassifier {
  virtual ~BinaryClassifier(){}
  virtual double classify(std::shared_ptr<Sample> sample) const = 0;
};
```

We may have several implementations of `BinaryClassifier`, e.g., `LogisticRegressionBinaryClassifier`.

The `Sample` is in turn an interface exposing only two methods:

```
struct Sample {
  virtual ~Sample() {}
  InputFeatures const& get_input_features() const = 0;
  double get_label() const = 0;
};
```

Apart from these two methods, concrete implementations of `Sample` expose quite different interfaces (i.e., they are unrelated), the only aspect they have in common is that they can be classified by a binary classifier.

So far so good.

Problems arise when we decide to introduce the `BinaryClassifier::train` method:

```
struct BinaryClassifier {
  virtual ~BinaryClassifier(){}
  virtual double classify(std::shared_ptr<Sample> sample) const = 0;
  virtual void train(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Sample>> samples) = 0;
};
```

At this point, the following won't work:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<ConcreteSample>> concreteSamples = ...;
concreteBinaryClassifier.train(concreteSamples);
```

that's because `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<ConcreteSample>>` and `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Sample>>` are two unrelated types.

The C++-ish solution would be to rely on templates:

```
      template<class SampleType>
      virtual void train(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<SampleType>> samples) = 0; // non-working code, template method cannot be virtual
```

But template methods cannot be `virtual`. Still, I would like `BinaryClassifier` to be a Strategy interface as many possible `BinaryClassifier` implementations may exist. At this point, even though the design seems quite resonable, I'm stuck at a dead end.

**EDIT:**  Moreover, it may happen for a given `BinaryClassifier` object to be trained with a vector of `ConcreteSampleA`, while classifying object of type `ConcreteSampleB`

Which is the right way of modeling this situation in the most C++-ish way?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your BinaryClassifier a template class

```
template<SampleType> class BinaryClassifier
{
    virtual void train(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<SampleType>> samples) = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is true but at this point what's the reason to have the `Sample` interface in the first place? Moreover, it may happen for a given `BinaryClassifier` object to be trained with a vector of `ConcreteSampleA`, while classifying object of type `ConcreteSampleB`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't train a `BinaryClassifier` on `ConcreteSampleA` and then use it to classify any random `ConcreteSampleB`. Therefore, the sample type is an inherent part of `BinaryClassifier`. Nullref's answer is reasonable there: make the sample type a template parameter.

As you discovered, that means there's no longer a need for a `Sample` interface. Good. `std::vector<int>` doesn't require that `int` is derived from some `Element` interface either.

While you're getting rid of stuff, `InputFeatures` looks suspect too. I'd just say that `get_input_features` must return some `std::tuple` whose member types all have `std::less` defined. Since it's no longer virtual, you don't care that different sample types return different tuples. And I definitely wouldn't hardcode that `get_label` must return a `double`. That's a weird label type anyway.

Now you said that it may make sense to train with a sample type A and then classify sample type B. That's where you get to a refinement: it seems that the actual compatibility requirement is that they return the same tuple. Therefore, a better solution that Nullref's is to templatize `BinaryClassifier` on the tuple type returned by `get_input_sample`.

[edit]
Furthermore, `classify` doesn't need to take co-ownership. Pass a `Sample const&`. `train()` really should take just an iterator pair. C++ convention is to pass a group of objects as a range.

Comment: Thanks for answering. It makes sense for a container `container<T>` not to require `T` to be derived by any specific base class. However, in this case I'm trying to enforce a specific requirement: `BinaryClassifier` only knows how to deal with `Sample`'s.  `InputFeatures` is just a `typedef` for `Eigen::RowVectorXd`, so it is pretty similar to your suggestion of using `std::tuple`. I modeled the label as a `double` as it can also be a soft-label. The classifier cannot be trained just by requiring the input features to be of the same type, it still needs to access the label.

Comment: @burton0: When you say "BinaryClassifier can only deal with Samples", don't you mean "it can only deal with classes which implement both `get_input_features` and `get_label`"? Just like vector can only deal with Movable and Assignable classes? I.e. require methods, not base classes.

Comment: About the ownership you're totally right, I wrote the code on the fly on SO, but the actual code uses references. `BinaryClassifier` can only deal with classes that implement both `get_input_features` and `get_label`. You can decide to enforce this by means of an interface, or make it a requirement via templates. The problem with templates is that you are fixing the concrete sample to use. Instead I would like to `train` and `classify` any sample, regardless its concrete implementation. Finally, an iterator of `shared_ptr<ConcreteSample>` is still not an iterator of `shared_ptr<Sample>`.